# Windows 10 terminal: Is it possible to have a dropdown or folders of SSH connections?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, terminal

My question is about the new windows 10 terminal

At work, I need to ssh to several servers daily. We have many clients, each client has between 3 to 5 servers I might need to ssh to.

Is it possible to organize the servers belonging to each client per folder or dropdown or something like that, like mobaxterm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could find, Windows Terminal does not support organizing profiles in folders.

You could, however, create many desktop shortcuts to `wt.exe` – one for each profile – and organize *those* into standard folders on your desktop or elsewhere. For example, a shortcut that needs to launch profile "Customer A Server 1" would need to run this command:

```
wt.exe -p "Customer A Server 1"
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments), it is even possible to launch multiple profiles in the same window by adding "new-tab" subcommands:

```
wt.exe -p "Customer A Server 1" ; new-tab -p "Customer A Server 2" ; focus-tab -t 1
```

This should allow you to create a single desktop shortcut to open all profiles for a single customer.

---

I would actually suggest that once the number of clients gets so large, instead of having a massive menu it will be faster to *type* the client's name or abbreviation directly into the command line.

If you use OpenSSH (the `ssh` command), it allows custom aliases to be assigned to servers, so for example instead of selecting "Customers / Fred's Used Cars / Server 1" you could type `ssh fred1`. (Then press Ctrl+Shift+T to open a new tab, type `ssh fred2`, press Ctrl+Shift+T again, type `ssh fred3`, repeat until all servers connected.)

To implement this, edit your `~\.ssh\config` file:

```
Host fred1
    Hostname webserver03.example.com
    User webdev
Host fred2
    Hostname webserver07.example.com
    User webdev
```

This works equally with all terminals and indeed with all operating systems.